# Hibernate: Map foreign key to part of composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` with the following structure:

TABLE_A

```
|------------|-----------|
| COMPANY_ID | (column)  |
|------------|-----------|
| SERVICE_ID | (column)  | 
|------------|-----------|
| .... other columns ..  |
|------------|-----------|

**COMPANY_ID and SERVICE_ID are composite Key**
-------------
```

TABLE_B :

```
|------------|-------------|
| ID         | (column)  PK|
|------------|-------------|
| COMPANY_ID | (column)    |
|------------|-------------|
| .... other columns ..    |
|------------|-------------|
```

So i want to map `TABLE_B.COMPANY_ID` (consider as a foreign key) to `TABLE_A.COMPANY_ID` (part of composite primary key)

I create the following code :

the Embeddable class :

```
@Embeddable
public class CompanyId implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long companyId;
private Long serviceId;

/**
 * Zero-args constructor 
 */
public CompanyId() {

}

/**
 * 
 * @param companyId
 * @param serviceId
 */
public CompanyId(Long companyId, Long serviceId) {

    this.companyId = companyId;
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
}

@Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
public Long getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(Long companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

@Column(name = "SERVICE_ID")
public Long getServiceId() {
    return serviceId;
}

public void setServiceId(Long serviceId) {
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(getCompanyId(), getServiceId());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    CompanyId other = (CompanyId) obj;
    if (companyId == null) {
        if (other.companyId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!companyId.equals(other.companyId))
        return false;
    if (serviceId == null) {
        if (other.serviceId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!serviceId.equals(other.serviceId))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

class model for TABLE_A

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class TableA implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private CompanyId id;


private Set<TableB> tableB = new HashSet<TableB>();

    @EmbeddedId
public CompanyId getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(CompanyId id) {
    this.id = id;
}


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMPANY_ID")
public Set<TableB> getTableB() {
    return tableB;
}

public void setTableB(Set<TableB> tableB) {
    this.tableB = tableB;
}
}
```

class model for TABLE_B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class TableB implements Serializable{

private Integer id;
private Set<TableA> tableA = new HashSet<TableA>();

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@MapsId("companyId")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMPANY_ID",   insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Set<TableA> getTableA() {
    return tableA;
}

public void setTableA(Set<TableA> tableA) {
    this.tableA = tableA;
}
}
```

but this code it does not work and i got the following error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection 
com.TableA.tableB

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
referencedColumnNames(COMPANY_ID) of com.TableB referencing com.TableA not 
mapped to a single property
```

so my question is :

It is possible to map single foreign key to part of composite key as descried above? if is how I can implement it?

Thanks

Comment: I have the distinct feeling that you don't fully understand [how a unidirectional one-to-many works](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany,_No_Inverse_ManyToOne,_No_Join_Table_(JPA_2.x_ONLY)). As regards your question, of course it's not possible, since `companyId` alone does not uniquely identify an instance of `TableA`. Are you sure `serviceId` should be part of the primary key? Perhaps what you need is a simple unique constraint?